# What's the best way to acquire a list of strings that match a string inside a string, by looking through a string list?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, regex, linq

Basically I have a string array that I am using to match inside a single string:

```
string[] matches = { "{A}", "{B}", "{CC}" };
```

Then I from these I look if I find any of these inside my string:

```
string text = "Lorem Ipsum is {CC} simply dummy text {A} of the {CC} printing and typesetting industry {B}."
```

In which case, the resulting array I want to gather should be:

```
string[] allmatches = { "{CC}", "{A}", "{CC}", "{B}" };
```

Is there an easy way to do this using LINQ or maybe Regex?

Comment: Do you want overlapping matches? For example, if `matches` is `"hello world", "ello"`. And the `text` is `"hello world!"`.

Comment: What have you tried, where do you struggle? Please show your code. And questions starting with 'What's the best way' tend to be off-topic. If you have questions regarding code improvements, please use SOs sister board [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `string[] matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b\{[A-Z]\}\b").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`? `Regex` and Linq

Comment: @Sweeper: No overlapping but my matches should be guaranteed not to overlap, they are unique.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: I just tried this but I get 0 matches.

Comment: @Jimi: Sorry I renamed that var now.

Comment: @Codereview: I have a code that works but it's rather cumbersome with nested for loops so I am looking for a more concise method to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the regex by first `Escape`ing each element in `matches` using `Select`, then `Join`ing with `|`. After that, get the `Matches` of the regex against `text` and `Select` the `Value`s:

```
var regex = string.Join("|", matches.Select(Regex.Escape));
var result = Regex.Matches(text, regex)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that `{A}..{Z}` are the only matches required, we can try combining `Regex` and Linq, e.g.

```
  string text = 
    @"Lorem Ipsum is {C} simply dummy text {A} of the {C} printing and typesetting industry {B}.";

  string[] allmatches = Regex
    .Matches(text, @"\{[A-Z]\}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    //.Where(item => matches.Contains(item)) // uncomment to validate matches
    .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", allmatches));
```

Outcome:

```
  {C}, {A}, {C}, {B}
```

**Edit:** uncomment `.Where(...)` if you want matches which are in `matches[]` only

**Edit 2:** If match doesn't necessary contain one letter only, change pattern:

```
  .Matches(text, @"\{[A-Z]+\}")    // one or more capital letters
  .Matches(text, @"\{[a-zA-Z]+\}") // one or more English letters
  .Matches(text, @"\{\p{L}+\}")    // one or more Unicode letters
  .Matches(text, @"\{[^}{]+\}")    // one or more characters except "{" and "}"
```

Comment: Thanks it works but is it possible to have the regex match anything between {}, rather than single character? Sometimes I have {ABC} also.

Comment: @Joan Venge: Just change *pattern* into `.Matches(text, @"\{[A-Z]+\}")`; note `+` which means *one or more* capital letters